# Adding feedback to an M/M/c queue

Tags: queueing-theory

I am trying to model a queue with the following properties:

- A multi-server/channel queuing model.
- Arrivals occur via a Poisson process and the service times are exponentially distributed.
- After service a customer may elect to rejoin the queue with some probability (more specifically, a customer would have a normally distributed budget of time after which they would leave).

As best as I can understand the literature this would seem to be an M/M/c queue with *feedback*, but though I have found a little about it, I can't find comprehensible closed-form equations I can apply to my specific modelling problem.

Is what I'm trying to do generally possible? And, if so, could someone try and point me in a productive direction? Many thanks.

Comment: If you assume that feedback packets go back to the same server they just left, it is just like increasing the service time.  The new service times are still exponential but the original service rate $\mu$ is now a rate $\mu p$, where $p$ is the probability of not being fed back.  So now you need $\lambda < c \mu p$ instead of just $\lambda < c\mu$.  Here I am assuming that service times are independently resized every time a job enters a server, even if that job has been in a server before.  This is the Kleinrock Independence Assumption.  This is just a special case of a Jackson network.

Comment: See Jackson networks here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_network

Comment: This is a wonderful insight and I believe exactly what I needed. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Michael presumably the service time would _decrease_ as a result of $cup$ right? I'm sure I'm misapprehending your point, but I'm imagining that $0 \le p \le 1$ and so it seems I can't just blindly swap out $cu$ for $cup$. 

Either way, I'm looking into the various leads you've provided and I'm sure it'll come together shortly.

Comment: The service time used to be a single exponential $X \sim exp(\mu)$ but now the service time increases to $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $N$ is independent $Geom(p)$, and it can be shown $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim exp(\mu p)$. So the service rate parameter decreases, which means the service times generally increase.